# Is there a way to set waiting limit on github a workflow?

Tags: github-actions

We use Github actions to deploy our code. Deploying to one of our environments require a review. According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments),

> If a job is not approved within 30 days, the workflow run will be automatically canceled.

Is it possible to change the 30 days to something else? I couldn't find anything in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) of workflows and I'd like to avoid having another workflow which would cancel workflows in Waiting status.

Comment: Did you try using the environment [Wait Timer](https://app.shortcut.com/stackspot/story/382360/import-de-stacks-via-alias-fase-1-do-registry)? Wouldn't it do the trick here?

Comment: The wait timer is delaying a job to start, however, my problem exactly is that the job is not started. My goal is to cancel the workflow if it is in Waiting state for some time.

Comment: I was actually wondering if there isn't a way to identify/check the wait timer has been used (instead of a manual approval) in the workflow to then cancel it automatically in that case.

Comment: I see. That could indeed work thanks for that, however, I'd prefer keeping the manual approval.